# Check SQLite Database exists

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

Is there a way of checking that a sqlite database exists in blackberry?  I have seen a suggestion that you can check it through the sdcard by going to media -> explore -> media options, however I am working on a simulator and do not have a sdcard.

Comment: If you close the simulator you must set the SDCard by following below instructions when again open the simulator. If anyone give solution and if it is correct then give the vote for him/her by click up arrow which is left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing on Simulator you have to attach SD card,for this go to

`Simulate->Chage SD card->Add Directory` in your simulator window header tabs.

To check your database go through your directory after adding.

Comment: If you close the simulator you must set the SDCard by following below instructions when again open the simulator. If anyone give solution and if it is correct then give the vote for him/her by click up arrow which is left side